# Does Eloquent have ability to get rows where one string field is in a string const?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a table called words (with a column named word), inside of which are a bunch of banned/blocked words. The user is asked to input a username at registration, and we check if any of the banned/blocked words are in the users chosen username.

I'm wondering if eloquent has a way for me to do this search...

So for example if the words table has the following entries in the word column, those words can NOT be in the username...

- bird
- chirp
- derp

So if the username chosen is "tychirply", it should be rejected because it has chirp in it.

I imagine eloquent might have a way to do this by returning any rows that are present in the string constant, otherwise I'll have to pull all words and handle the check via PHP.

I'm running laravel 5.3, this is how I do it now....

```
$search_words = Words::where('is_badname', true)->get();
foreach($search_words as $search_word)
{
    if (strpos($word, $search_word->word) !== false)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create your own Validation Rule according to this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules it could be something like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use App\Words;

class BannedWords implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $words = Words::where('is_badname', true)->get();
        return (strpos($word, $words->toArray()) !== false);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'This word is forbidden.';
    }
}
```